# Visual Studio 2017 does not prompt to save changed files before rebuild

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

This is pretty trivial but very annoying. I upgraded a solution from VS 2010 to VS 2017.  In VS 2010 if I modified a file in the Source Code Editor and then clicked Build, it would prompt me with:

> Save changes to the following items? Yes, No or Cancel

However in VS 2017 it just saves the files and builds without a prompt.  Is there a way to modify the settings of VS 2017 to act the same way as VS 2010?  I searched through all the settings but could not find it.

Comment: Why is that annoying? Why do you need to be asked before save?

Comment: That is my preference.  For example, via errant keystrokes I might have inadvertently modified a file I did not intend to.  It has happened.  Do you know how to modify that setting?

Comment: Even you have this option, you may save some errant keystrokes, too. Most errant key strokes will give a gramma error in place so there is no big impact. The chance of success compile on errant keystroke is small chance multiply small chance. You may file a feature request to VS support site anyway.